# Javascript (Greasemonkey) : maximize newly opened windows

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, xpcom

I try to code a Greasemonkey javascript snippet to have new windows opened maximized by Firefox.

Here's my code :

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Maximize windows
// @namespace   maxiwin
// @include     http://*.*
// @include     https://*.*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==
if (window.windowState != 1){
  dc = window.getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMChromeWindow);
  dc.maximize();
}
```

But it doesn't work. Also tried :

```
if (window.windowState != 1){
  var domchrome = Components.Constructor("@mozilla.org/nsidomchromewindow;1");
  var dc = new domchrome();
  dc = dc.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMChromeWindow);
  dc.maximize();
}
```

It doesn't work either.
Does a Greasemonkey specialist have a solution ?

Comment: I am 99% sure JavaScript cannot alter any actual window properties.

Comment: window.open() ? *var windowObjectReference = window.open(strUrl, strWindowName, [strWindowFeatures]);*

Comment: I do not want to open a window but maximize an already opened one. In the Mozilla doc, XPcom is supposed to be able to maximize a window with nsIDOMChromeWindow (scriptable with javascript/greasemonkey). But I'm not sure about the syntax of my code, specially the contractID.

Comment: This is probably easier to do in a addon, where you don't need to use xpcom and have a nice API for [windows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Working_with_windows_in_chrome_code

Comment: I found another solution, use a small program called AutoSizer. But I'm still interested is someone can answer the greasemonkey question.